# DKIM signing emails using Postfix with removed headers

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I have a problem getting OpenDKIM working with Postfix. Due to security reasons we remove certain headers from our emails:

From main.cf:

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

The headers removed are as follows:

```
/^Received:.*with ESMTPSA/              IGNORE
/^X-Originating-IP:/     IGNORE
/^X-Mailer:/             IGNORE
/^Mime-Version:/         IGNORE
```

However this makes the opendkim fail:

```
Nov 22 19:26:15 localhost opendkim[5104]: BC4F5406A9: can't determine message sender; accepting
```

Is there any way to have the headers removed *and* getting opendkim work?

Comment: I have the same problem when using multi instances. The first instance works but the new instance fails with the message above.

Comment: Btw... are you using multiple postfix instances?

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution here. Instead of removing the header that caused the problem we simply rewrite the IP address:

https://we.riseup.net/debian/mail#getting-your-postfix-anonymized

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the same problem was to add the "Reply-To: " field. Apparently OpenDKIM is using this when the "Received: " part is missing.
Note that Outlook didn't add by default, I had to set it in mailbox settings.